# Changing style sheets for entire website at runtime using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

So i'm using xhtml and css to create a website.
I have no Javascript experience but used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=9&v=_XAQH41rjio) turorial in order to change style sheets at runtime using a button.

So the code in my head was

```
<link id="pagestyle"
        rel = "stylesheet"
        href = "projectstylesheet.css"
        type = "text/css"
        />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function swapStyleSheet(sheet) {
                document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', 
sheet);
            }
        </script>
```

and the code for my button was

```
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('projectstylesheetalternate.css')">
                Alternate Stylesheet
</button>
```

How would I let the stylesheet change stick, so it doesn't revert to the original stylesheet when I switch pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options to make the stylesheet change permanent:

1. You develop your Website in a way that doesn't require real page reloads e.g. by asynchronously loading new content. The users "stylesheet decision" is then saved until he hits the reload button
2. On button click you also send a request to the server and save the stylesheet path in the users session data. The users decision is then saved for as long as the session lasts, which is usually until the user quits their browser.
3. You store the stylesheet path in a cookie, the localStorage or cache it somewhere else in the client. The change is then permanent until the user clears its cookies, cache etc.
4. You make the user sign up on your page and - similar to approach 1 - make a request to the server on button click. But this time you don't store the value in the session but in a database table which is linked/part of the users profile.
   The change is then really permanent and as long as you don't provide a way to change the stylesheet back there is no way for the user to do so (apart from registering a new account)

I think Solution No. 3 suits your needs best. So you might want to use a library like [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) to to achieve this.